# Consulta a la BD me devuelve NULL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy intentando hacer una paginacion con PHP y este problema me esta volviendo loco. Cuando hago la query para obtener la cantidad de registros de una tabla de la base de datos me devuelve NULL pero cuando meto la query manualmente en la base de datos funciona correctamente.

```
 <?php

          require_once './includes/functions/db_conection.php';
          $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM articles";

          if (!$resultado = $conn->query($sql)) {
            
            echo "Lo sentimos, este sitio web está experimentando problemas.";
            echo "<br>";
            var_dump($resultado);
            echo "<br>";
    
            echo "Error: La ejecución de la consulta falló debido a: \n";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Errno: " . $conn->errno . "\n";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Error: " . $conn->error . "\n";
            exit;
        }
        
        if ($resultado->num_rows == 0) {
           
            echo "Lo sentimos. No hay registros en la bd";
            exit;
        }
        
        $articulo = $resultado->fetch_assoc();

        ?>
```

El resultado es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y no continua cargando la pagina.
La conexion a la base de datos es correcta porque la uso para otras consultas y no me dio ningun problema.
No se si ayuda pero si hago un var_dump de la variable que se conecta a la base de datos ($conn) en una funcion en cual funciona bien, depues de ejecutar la query, el resultado es el siguiente [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] y si hago un var_dump de la misma variable pero en este archivo que me esta dado problemas, despues de ejecutar la query el resultado es otro, es este [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] no entiendo bien que significa, como si nunca se hubiera echo un llamado a la BD

Comment: Por favor pon esto en tu código `if($conn === FALSE){ die(print_r(mysqli_error(),TRUE));}`, lo que quiero ver es si efectivamente hay conexión a la DB. Saludos.

Comment: Lo puse en mi codigo y no muestra nada en la pagina

Comment: ¿Si ejecutas la consulta en MySQL te genera algún resultado?

Comment: Si, anda perfectamente la consulta en MySQL!

Comment: Entiendo, lo que me llama la atención es que la conexión trae `null` en todo, lo que creo es que puede estar fallando la referencia, ¿el `path` de la conexión es correcto?

Answer (score 0):

no veo que estés igualando la variable $resultado o al menos en el código no lo miro,
intenta igualarlo algo parecido a esto

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

Comment: Continua devolviendo null

Comment: ya obtuve el resultado basicamente tienes que acceder a ello con esto  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['total'] . "<br>";
        }

Comment: mandaria foto pero luego me dicen que no es necesario

Comment: te mando el link de descarga espero te sea de ayuda https://mega.nz/file/OGp3TQLS#mj8F9ROGaR0J_uMHdvom9R4kKmmAyuGCyxzxi4slbtw

Comment: No me funciona porque no se puede hacer un fetch_assoc() a un NULL

Comment: :s bueno al menos tienes una parte en donde te devuelve el total, al menos eso funciona jeje, perdon si no fue de ayuda

Comment: jajaj gracias por tomarte el tiempo! Seguire investigando!

Comment: que datos quieres obtener con fetch_assoc() ??

Comment: La consulta me tiene que traer la cantidad de registros que hay una tabla con el nombre total entonces lo que quiero hacer es acceder a esos datos de esta forma `$cantidad-articulos = $result->fetch_assoc()` siendo `$result = $conn->query($sql);`

Comment: es que el fetch_assoc se utiliza con un while de esta forma y le dices los datos que quieres obtener, sin embargo nomas en la consulta obtienes el puro total y lo guardas en una variable                                                                                      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       
        $guardar = $row['total'];
   
    }

Comment: Es correcto, pero si haces el fetch_assoc fuera del while tambien funciona. Solamente va a mostrar un dato por asi decirlo pero funciona. Mi problema es que no puedo hacer fetch assoc porque tengo NULL

Comment: jajaja nunca he utilizado el fetch_assoc de esa forma, ya hay no se, jeje sorry

Comment: si obtienes un solo dato se puede utilizar como asi como dices, pero como tienes * se supone que tienes varios datos ya que a mi me marca este error Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\task-app\prubea.php on line 62 pero no me da vacio o al menos  a mi no

Comment: Claro! Esto es lo que me devuelve esa columna https://imgur.com/9U1vVM2 pero el problema es que no me devuelve eso en php, me devuelve NULL

Comment: intenta lo siguiente pon un select  where id = 1 y utiliza el fetch_assoc, entonces hay si deberia de funcionar, pero en php a mi si me devuelve el valor que es solamente que no lo permite porque es un count(*) es por eso que se utiliza el while, pero si se a lo que te refieres jeje

Comment: No puedo poner el where que decis porque no tengo un id y el problema no es el fetch assoc ni el while. Le problema es que no me trae nada de la base de datos cuando hago el $conn->query($sql)

Comment: aaaa jajaja pense que tu problema era lo otro, ya se que es lo mismo pero lo intentaste de esta forma ? 
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);